Rollup: Could not resolve component from "src/index.ts"
I am trying to create my own npm package for a react component. I am getting the following error:

Here is the project structure that I am using

Here's my index.ts file
import LeetcodeCalendar from "./components/LeetcodeCalendar";

export default LeetcodeCalendar;

My rollup.config.mjs
import commonjs from "@rollup/plugin-commonjs";
import resolve from "@rollup/plugin-node-resolve";
import terser from "@rollup/plugin-terser";
import typescript from "@rollup/plugin-typescript";
import { readFileSync } from 'fs';
import dts from "rollup-plugin-dts";
import peerDepsExternal from "rollup-plugin-peer-deps-external";

const packageJson = JSON.parse(readFileSync(new URL('./package.json', import.meta.url), 'utf8'));

export default [
  {
    input: "src/index.ts",
    output: [
      {
        file: packageJson.main,
        format: "cjs",
        sourcemap: true,
      },
      {
        file: packageJson.module,
        format: "esm",
        sourcemap: true,
      },
    ],
    plugins: [
      peerDepsExternal(),
      resolve({ extensions: [".js", ".ts", ".jsx", ".tsx"] }),
      commonjs(),
      typescript({
        noEmitOnError: true,
        tsconfig: './tsconfig.json',
        declaration: true,
        declarationDir: 'dist',
     }),
      terser(),
    ],
    external: ["react", "react-dom"],
  },
  {
    input: "src/index.ts",
    output: [{ file: packageJson.types, format: "es" }],
    plugins: [dts.default],
  },
];

tsconfig.json file
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "ES5",
    "lib": ["dom", "dom.iterable", "esnext"],
    "allowJs": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "strict": true,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "noFallthroughCasesInSwitch": true,
    "module": "esnext",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "isolatedModules": true,
    "noEmit": false,
    "jsx": "react-jsx",
    "rootDir": "src"
  },
  "include": ["src/**/*"],
  "exclude": ["node_modules", "dist"]
}

I have tried the following:

Initially I was using "rollup.config.js" now with esm module
I have tried merging my component/LeetcodeCalendar directly as index.tsx file... This creates various more error.
When I work with this component in a react project, it works. However, I am unable to create a npm package out of it.

Attaching image for package.json

